# http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194416/was-not-to-be-closed-construct

Tags: discussion

Is this an English language site?

Then, why has ["It was not to be closed" or "It should not have been closed"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194416/was-not-to-be-closed-construct) got a lot of downvotes?

The construct which I was refering to is a difficult one therefore the question deserves at least an answer.

Comment: Probably needs a lot more explanation...and then maybe better on ELL.

Comment: Unfortunately, that particular question has been edited to be off-topic, although it wasn't really on-topic before the edit.

Comment: Hi Elberich. My feeling is that it got closed by the readership here from Meta and they were a bit worried that the quote was from one of their comments ....

Comment: @Araucaria The only such comment I can find was made in December 2012 (on a question which is indeed not closed), but perhaps my Google-fu isn't as good as it could be. However, I closed the subject of *this* post and I'm confident that the quote is not from one of my comments.

Answer (score 8):

Downvotes are not related to 'deserves an answer' (whatever you mean by that; why do you *deserve* somebody else's time?). The reasons for downvotes are, and as far as I know always have been, "This question does not show research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Your question shows no effort of any sort, whether research or analysis: with no context at all it is entirely unclear; and with no explanation of what you mean by 'right', it is never going to be useful. Are you really surprised that people voted it down?